# Double tag badges today?

Tags: bug, badges

Today I was awarded a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) badge twice; shows up in notifications and my profile and on the tag page. Why the double award?

[image: Two Lists]
[image: Profile badges]

Comment: Most likely a race condition with multiple runs of the cron to award badges?

Comment: Tag badges, unlike other badges, can be stripped out if the conditions are not met... so just delete some of your list answers :D

Comment: Maybe that is caused at the leap second this night^^

Comment: ^^ Wasn't that in June 2016?

Comment: @anishsane The last leap second was on the last second of 2016.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that... In 2015, it was in June... Thanks for info. :-)

Comment: gorgeous two-flavored free-hand red circles